# Can we assign query_param value to a field in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a `views.py`

```
class ProductImageAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductImageSerializer
    
    def post(self, request):
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data = request.data, context = query_params)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField()
    product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null = False, read_only = True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['id', 'image', 'product']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        productParam = self.context.get('product')
        return super().validate(attrs)
```

I'm sending the `query_params` as a context into the serializer. I want to know, how can I assign `product` field with the `productParam` value so that i can validate it and use it in `fields` section of Meta class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve it out by overriding the **`create`** method of `serializers.py`

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    productId = self.context.get('product') # This is the query param obtained
    product = Product.objects.get(id = productId)
    validated_data['product'] = product
    return super().create(validated_data)
```